# Is it only subscribers that get certain mission rewards?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've just started playing Star Wars: The Old Republic and noticed that certain mission rewards seem to be locked and dissapear when I 'Accept' the mission end dialog. There's a tooltip that mentions subscribers but I can't recall the precise wording.

Are these locked rewards, which seem so far to only be credit lockboxes, only available to subscribers or can I get them by adding some Cartel Coins and becoming a preferred player? I've tried searching but haven't found a definitive answer only a lot of forum rage about lockbox gambling in general.

Secondly is there any way to recover these lockboxes if I become a subscriber or are they gone forever?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some rewards are only for subs.  [See this for the rationale](http://www.swtor.com/support/helpcenter/6820).

They're only for current subscribers, and there's no way to go back and get past rewards once you've subbed.  Some details on what Preferred players get: [this Support article](http://www.swtor.com/support/helpcenter/6817) and [the comparison grid](http://www.swtor.com/free/features).

Note that this is separate from the credit escrow — any credits you gain while you have more than 200k (as F2P) are given back to you if you sub.